# Fetching page source

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in my page

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>testpage</title>
    <script language = 'javascript'>function fchange(){alert(document.getElementById("ifrm").value);</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id = 'ifrm' src = 'http://www.google.com' width = '700' height='500'></iframe><input type='button' onclick = 'fchange()' value = 'clickhere'>
</body>
</html>
```

From this I click the button and an alert box dispalys `undefined`. But I need the content or the source of the page ('http://www.google.com'). Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

If you want the source of the iframe, you would need to access the document object of the iframe.

```
function fchange() 
{
    alert(document.getElementById("ifrm").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
}
```

As mentioned by others, you cannot get the source of an iframe which points to a page outside your domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, as it breaks the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy).

If both pages are on the same domain then you can with do what @Joel suggests, or the slightly more old fashioned:

```
window.frames['ifrm'].document.body.innerHTML;
```

You'll need `<iframe name="ifrm" ...>` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have back-end script for that. I think that's the only way. AJAX would not allow to make a request to other domains for security reasons.